# How to retrieve data from the database using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two models/tables, one is User and the other is role the relationship is one Role can have many users. I am trying to loop through the data in the user model navigation property but i am getting an error that its returning null.

User model

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int User_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="User Name")]
    public string User_Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Field Is Required")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = " Please Enter A Valid Input")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    //Nav

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    [Display(Name ="User Role:")]
    public int RoleId { get; set;}

    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Role Model

```
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int  Role_id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="This field is required")]
    [Display(Name ="Role Name :")]
    public string RoleType { get; set; }
    
    //nav
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

Controller action Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var viewModel = await userRepository.GetAllUsersAlongWithRolesAsync();

            //var viewModel = await baseRepository.GetAllObjectsAsync();

            return View("Index",viewModel);
        }
```

[image: the Error]

**Updates**: `UserRepository` that inherited from the `IBaseRepository`

```
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _Context;

    public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext context):base (context)
    {
        _Context = context;
    }

    public async Task <IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUsersAlongWithRolesAsync()
    {
        var getUsers = await _Context.Users.Include(u => u.Role).ToListAsync();

        return getUsers;
    }
}
```

In the User controller for injecting:

```
// injection
private readonly IBaseRepository<User> baseRepository;

private readonly IBaseRepository<Role> roleRepository;

private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

public UserController(IBaseRepository<User> _baseRepository, IBaseRepository<Role> _roleRepository, IUserRepository userRepository)
{
    baseRepository = _baseRepository;
    this.roleRepository = _roleRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

Comment: Did you checked the `role` if that exist? This the screenshot is for `view` can you please share the related controller details?

Comment: How (in code) did you load the user to be displayed in that view? Did you use `.Include(u => u.Role)` to also load the `Role` object with all its properties?

Comment: where i suppose to write this line of code and i guess that's the answer

Comment: @marc_s how can i use your suggestion

Comment: `baseRepository.Include(x => x.User).ThenInclude(u => u.Role).GetAllObjectsAsync()`

Comment: What does your `baseRepository.GetAllObjectsAsync()` method look like?

Comment: @klekmek where to put this edit

Comment: Your code is still very much incomplete - can't really tell what you're doing, and what might be the cause for the error. Basically, *somewhere* you need something like : `User myUser = dbContext.User.Where(u => u.Id == id)?.Include(u => u.Role);` or something like that - you need to **explicitly** call `.Include` to load the dependent property - all the code I've seen so far to does **NOT** do that and thus your `myUser.Role` will be NULL ....

Comment: @marc_s the GetAllObjectsAsync function is a function inside the repository class, all i am doing is making a service layer which holds all the logic which in this case it's the repository class and i am calling this function in the controller to get all the Users but the only thing that i am missing i how to add your suggestion code in my code, u can edit the `GetAllObjectsAsync` which it's a function inside repository class and has access to the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your method `GetAllObjectsAsync` is so generic, you probably won't be able to add the `.Include()` you need.

I'd suggest a separate method `GetAllUsers()` to your repository - possibly the concrete `UserRepository`, if you have that:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUsersAsync()
{
    var getUsers = await _Context.Users.Include(u => u.Role).ToListAsync();

    return getUsers;
}
```

Comment: first thanks so much for your answer and it seems correct but i got another error this is the error title `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Interfaces.IUserRepository' while attempting to activate 'InventoryManagmentSystem.Controllers.UserController'.
`

Comment: I updated the code can u check it if u got time, i think it's about when i inject IUserRepository

Comment: @HeshamEldawy: most likely, you haven't added a service registration for `IUserRepository` to your startup class (for .NET Core - or whatever DI repo you're using), so the dependency injection system can't find what concrete class to use for `IUserRepository` when injecting dependencies.

Comment: okay i am sorry still didn't get what u are trying to say but what's your recommendation to solve the problem. i injected the IUserRepository correctly i think

Comment: @HeshamEldawy: yes, you **injected** it correctly - but the **DI container** (either in .NET Core, or any other DI container you might be using) doesn't know about `IUserRepository` yet. Somewhere, you must be configuring/defining your DI container - there, you need to add the registration for "use `UserRepository` whenever someone asks for the `IUserRepository` interface")